# Can I use a variable for the 'To' field for Twilio SMS?

Tags: twilio-php

I keep getting an error: "RestException: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'To'..."

when trying to use a variable - see below, example = $user_phone_number = "+13334445555"

```
------------------------------------------------------------
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
      
$client->messages->create(
  // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
  $user_phone_number,
  array(
   'from' => $twilio_number,
   'body' => $MsgBody
  )
);
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What's the rest of that error message? After "The 'To'..."?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'To' number +1617xxxxxxx is not a valid phone number.

Comment: It works fine if I type the number: $client->messages->create(
    // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
    '+15558675310',
    array(
        'from' => $twilio_number,
        'body' => 'I sent this message in under 10 minutes!'
    )

Comment: Are you using a  free account? And is the number you are trying to send to a [verified number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio)?

Comment: Yes it's a free account - am sending 'to' my verified mobile number - using the twilio number in the 'from' field

Comment: Has that mobile number that you are sending to been [verified](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio)?